# How to read dropzone files

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

How to read the files from the dropzone ,i can able to drag and drop the files into the dropzone but i am not getting how to read the files which are dropped into the dropzone ,How to access the dropped file in to the action class i am using struts 1.1 .,could you please help me out on this.

Here is the code snippet for the dropzone which i used.i have created a ajax call inside dropzone ,which will pass the file name to the action class,but i am getting only string value instead i need list of files which are dropped into the dropzone

```
$(function() {      
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-dropzone");
    myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) {

        $.ajax({ type: "POST", async: false, url: "/x/abc.do", data: { filename: file } })
                            .done(function( msg ) { console.log( " Uplaod -> " + msg ); });
    });
});
```

and i am reading the file name in action class like below

```
String file = request.getParameter("filename");
```

above line is giving only file name,but i need file size and list of files which i dropped in to the dropbox

Note:i am using struts ,how to use enctype for the dropzone.

Could you please help me out on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dropzone event to achieve this.

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false; // Disabling autoDiscover, otherwise Dropzone will try to attach twice.

$(function() {      
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-dropzone");
    myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) {
        /* Maybe display some more file information on your page */
    });
});
```

Comment: How to access the dropped file in to action calss

Comment: "addedfile" event  is fired when a file is added to the list. you will get file info in callback of this.

Comment: Just file info. Not the file. How to read the actual file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use FileReader if file is not too large. Answer is shown in [react-dropzone github page](https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone).

```
$(function() {      
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-dropzone");
    myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) {

const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => {
            const fileAsBinaryString = reader.result;
            // do whatever you want with the file content
        };
        reader.onabort = () => console.log('file reading was aborted');
        reader.onerror = () => console.log('file reading has failed');

        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);

        $.ajax({ type: "POST", async: false, url: "/x/abc.do", data: { filename: file } })
                            .done(function( msg ) { console.log( " Uplaod -> " + msg ); });
    });
});
```

You can also use other functions than `readAsBinaryString`. Such as `readAsText(file, 'UTF-8')`. All of them are listed in [MDN Website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader).